# Para que servem os operadores | & << >>?

Tags: javascript, operadores

Estava analisando um [código](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_decode/) e encontrei alguns operadores dos quais não conheço: `|`, `&`, `>>` e `<<`. Qual a funcionalidade destes operadores?

```
bits = h1 << 18 | h2 << 12 | h3 << 6 | h4;

o1 = bits >> 16 & 0xff;
o2 = bits >> 8 & 0xff;
o3 = bits & 0xff;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Estes são chamados de [operadores *bitwise*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). Eles fazem operações diretamente nos *bits* do dado numérico.

Os dois primeiros são o *or* e o *and* e funcionam de forma semelhante ao `||` e `&&` mas o cálculo booleano é feito *bit* por *bit* do número. A grosso modo podemos dizer que o *or* faz uma soma dos *bits* e o *and* faz uma multiplicação. [Tabela verdade destas e outras operações](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porta_l%C3%B3gica).

Os dois seguintes são operadores de *shift* ou deslocamento de *bits*. O primeiro vai empurrando os *bits* para a direita complementando o espaço que fica na esquerda com 0. Os *bits* que vão mais à direita vão sendo descartados. E o segundo faz em direção oposta. Cada *bit* deslocado à esquerda multiplica o número por 2 e no deslocamento à direita ele é dividido por 2.

Como pode ser vista na documentação da MDN *linkada* acima ainda existem os operadores de *xor* (ou exclusivo) e de *not* que é a negação. Lembrando que sempre é feito *bit* a *bit*.

Todas estas operações são feitas sempre em números 32 bits.

Um uso muito comum é para acumular *flags* como demostrado abaixo. Também é usado em manipulações de dados científicos, imagens (principalmente cores) e outras formas de mídia, criptografia, compressão, *checksum* para comunicação de dados, máquinas de estados, enfim, é só usar a criatividade.

Em geral é considerada programação de baixo nível e inclusive muitas vezes é usado como forma de otimização, apesar que às vezes há abusos. `x / 2` é equivalente à `z >> 1` e `x & 1 == 0` é equivalente à `x % 2 == 0`

É possível entender em detalhes como o cálculo é feito no [artigo da Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B3gica_bin%C3%A1ria) ([em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)).

```
var flags = 5;                       // em binário equivale a 0101
var FLAG_A = 1;                      // 0001
var FLAG_B = 2;                      // 0010
var FLAG_C = 4;                      // 0100
var FLAG_D = 8;                      // 1000
var mask = FLAG_A | FLAG_B | FLAG_D; // 0001 | 0010 | 1000 => 1011
if (flags & FLAG_C) {                // 0101 & 0100 => 0100 => true
   // faz alguma coisa
}
if ((flags & FLAG_B) || (flags & FLAG_C)) {
   // faz alguma coisa
}
var mask = FLAG_B | FLAG_C;          // 0010 | 0100 => 0110
if (flags & mask) {                  // 0101 & 0110 => 0100 => true
   // faz alguma coisa
}
var mask = FLAG_C | FLAG_D;          // 0100 | 1000 => 1100
flags |= mask;                       // 0101 | 1100 => 1101
var mask = ~(FLAG_A | FLAG_C);       // ~0101 => 1010
flags &= mask;                       // 1101 & 1010 => 1000
var mask = ~FLAG_A & ~FLAG_C;
flags &= mask;                       // 1101 & 1010 => 1000
var mask = FLAG_B | FLAG_C;
flags = flags ^ mask;                // 1100 ^ 0110 => 1010
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Operators/Bitwise.js).

Exemplos retirados da documentação da MDN.

Comment: Talvez valha a pena mencionar (já que esse detalhe me pegou despercebido antes) que não importa o tamanho ou o tipo do número, ele é convertido em um inteiro de 32 bits antes de qualquer operação *bitwise*.

Comment: @mgibsonbr não sabia disto mas está mencionado por você :)

Comment: Na mesma [documentação na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) linkada na sua resposta isso é explicitado, veja sob "Signed 32-bit integers". À primeira vista parece um detalhe bobo, até insignificante, até que ele volta pra te morder... :P

Answer (score 10):

Olá,esses caracteres são operadores binários em JS, ou seja, as operações são feitas a nível de bit:

```
Operator    Description     Example     Same as     Result  Decimal
&           AND             x = 5 & 1   0101 & 0001 0001    1
|           OR              x = 5 | 1   0101 | 0001 0101    5
<<          Left shift      x = 5 << 1  0101 << 1   1010    10
>>          Right shift     x = 5 >> 1  0101 >> 1   0010    2
```

fonte: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Mais sobre operadores binários: http://www.universidadejava.com.br/docs/operadoresbitabit