# Como funcionam os operadores de bit?

Tags: c, c++, operadores, bitwise

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
volatile long Hex_To_int(long Hex , char bits)
{

  long Hex_2_int;
  char byte; 

  Hex_2_int = 0 ; 

  for(byte = 0 ; byte < bits ; byte++)
  {

     if(Hex& (0x0001 << byte)) Hex_2_int += 1*(pow(2,byte));

     else Hex_2_int  += 0*(pow(2,byte));

  }

  return Hex_2_int;
}
```

Como é que funciona o `if` com operadores de `bit` nessa seguinte comparação?

```
if(Hex& (0x0001 << byte))
```

Comment: O `if` funciona igual, não importa o que tem nele, você quer saber como o operador de *shift* funciona? Seja mais específico.

Comment: Quero saber o contexto da operação . oque esta fazendo

Comment: Repara que somar `0` (ou `0 * qualquer coisa`) é o mesmo que não somar: podes remover o `else` do código :-)

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

O código é estranho e faz coisas desnecessárias.

A operação de *shift* (operador `<<`) desloca os bits para a esquerda. Como a posição determina o número representado, como no decimal, cada bit deslocado para a esquerda multiplica por 2 (a base do binário) o valor existente (assim como deslocar um dígito para a esquerda no decimal multiplica por 10, a base do decimal). Neste caso cada passada pelo laço produzirá 1, 2, 4, 8, etc.

O resultado será calculando com a variável `Hex` fazendo uma operação de *and* (`operador &`). O *and* funciona de forma semelhante à multiplicação, ou seja, cada bit que um operando é calculado com o bite correspondente do outro operando. O resultado será 1 sempre que ambos sejam 1 e 0 quando não houver esta coincidência.

O resultado final sendo um valor diferente de zero executa o `if`, já que, em C, isto é considerado verdadeiro. Se o resultado for 0, executa o `else`.

[Saiba mais aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52949/101). A linguagem é diferente mas o funcionamento é o mesmo.

Comment: Ya ... simplificando fica: `unsigned long Hex_To_int(unsigned long Hex, char bits) { return Hex & ((1 << bits) - 1); }`