# Armazenar mais de um valor em uma variável com &&

Tags: c, c++, variáveis, operadores

Consigo armazenar mais de um numero em uma variável? Por exemplo:

```
m= a&&b&&c&&d&&e
```

Eu preciso indicar qual é o maior e o menor numero que o usuário inseriu, queria um jeito de fazer isso sem precisar testar um por um.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Respondendo a pergunta: não é possível. [Variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é apenas um nome para uma posição da memória onde cabe **um** e apenas um valor.

É possível ter uma variável com um conjunto de variáveis, ela é chamada de [*array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124849/101), então o conteúdo dessas variáveis são os elementos contidos dentro dela, mas o conjunto de elementos como um todo é considerado um valor. E cada elemento é uma variável que possui um só valor.

É possível fazer cálculos que podem transformar vários valores em apenas um. Assim como pode fazer `1 + 2 + 3` virar 6.

Geralmente o cálculo de bits é feito com [`&`, `|` e `~`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91049/101). Em geral é mais difícil de entender, nem todos os casos compensam o uso.

Para saber o que usar precisaríamos entender melhor o problema. Mas pelo que informou me parece que terá que comparar um por um, a forma de comparar é que pode mudar.

Comment: é uma questão de um teste: Faça um programa que peça ao usuário 5 números e indique o maior e o menor deles. Para comparar usei o formato: a>b&&a>c&&a>d&&a>e.

Comment: @helena isso soa como [o problema XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa); essa sua pergunta já foi respondida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195964/maior-menor-soma-em-c-usando-for/201170).