# Para que serve o operador << no contexto de paginação de memória virtual?

Tags: c, c++, operadores, sistema-operacional

Estou vendo a implementação de memória virtual e tenho este código:

```
#define INDEX_FROM_BIT(a) (a / 8*4)
#define OFFSET_FROM_BIT(a)(a % (8*4))



static void set_frame(u32int frame_addr)
{

    u32int frame = frame_addr/0x1000;

    u32int idx = INDEX_FROM_BIT(frame);

    u32int off = OFFSET_FROM_BIT(frame);

    frames[idx] |=(0x1 << off);
}

static void clear_frame(u32int frame_addr)
{
    u32int frame = frame_addr/0x1000;

    u32int idx = INDEX_FROM_BIT(frame);

    u32int off = OFFSET_FROM_BIT(frame);

    frames[idx] &= ~(0x1 << off);

}
```

Porque esse `(0x01 << off)` e tão usado qual seu contexto para memoria virtual?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Este é o [operador de deslocamento de bits](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52949/101). É mais rápido que fazer exponenciação quando a base é 2.

O uso em [memória virtual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214744/101) é amplo, depende de cada contexto.

Obviamente o acesso à memória física é feito sempre através de cálculos em relação ao endereço virtual original. Também precisa fazer marcações de onde está cada página. Enfim, depende da implementação mas o campo da computação como um todo se beneficia de operações de manipulações diretas de bits porque nossa área trabalha naturalmente com números e conjuntos baseados em 2.