# O que é segmentação de memória?

Tags: memória, gerenciamento-de-memória

Li  a respeito de [segmentação de memória](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(mem%C3%B3ria)), porém, não consigo entender o que de fato é segmentação de memória e como ela influencia no funcionamento do meu programa.

## Ilustração

Veja este exemplo de programa que gera um erro de *segmentation fault*:

```
int main(void)
{
    int* v = NULL;
    *v = 3;

    return 0;
}
```

---

## Dúvidas

1. O que é segmentação de memória?
2. Como a segmentação de memória influencia no funcionamento do meu
   programa?
3. O *segmentation fault* gerado pelo programa acima esta relacionado com
   a segmentação de memória ou é outra coisa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lembra do [*page fault*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207174/101)? É parecido, mas o motivo é diferente. A falha de página é inerente ao [sistema de memória virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). A falha de segmentação é um *bug* no código (provavelmente).

Ele ocorre quando tenta acessar uma memória que não está disponível para sua aplicação. Ela não foi alocada (reservada) para o processo em execução. Também ocorre quando o acesso é feito em páginas protegidas no processo, em geral mais quando está fazendo escrita.

## Seu erro

Você não pode escrever no endereço 0 da memória da sua aplicação. E não é só o 0, outros também são reservados. Na verdade nem ler no 0. Você não pode escrever na parte de código (salvo privilégio especial), o código é fixo, é estático. O mesmo ocorre com a parte de dados estáticos (em geral colocados por literais no seu código).

Lembrando que o endereço de memória em questão é virtual, nada tem a ver com a memória física.

> O que é Segmentação de Memória?

Áreas da memória onde cada parte está:

- o código binário executando
- [dados estáticos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss)
- [memória estática, dinâmica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment)
- partes que só o sistema operacional deveria acessar
- partes protegidas a pedido da aplicação
- etc.

São os segmentos, cada um com uma configuração diferente no sistema operacional. Estes segmentos costumam ser formados por várias páginas.

[image: Esquema de segmentos de memória]

Ele pode ocorrer sempre que fizer uma operação não permitida, de leitura, escrita ou execução. É como na *filesystem* quando tenta acessar um arquivo sem permissão para aquilo.

> Como a Segmentação de Memória influencia no funcionamento do meu programa?

Para o desenvolver comum nada, mas ali tem toda organização de como o processo tratará o que está em memória. Claro que ele não pode tentar fazer operações em segmentos não permitidos nas linguagens que permitem isso.

> O segmentation fault gerado pelo programa acima esta relacionado com a Segmentação de Memória ou é outra coisa?

Esse erro ocorre por acessar algo que não está autorizado naquele contexto. Isso não ocorre em linguagens com memória gerenciada, a não ser por *bug* no *runtime* ou máquina virtual da linguagem.

Esses *bugs* ocorrem frequentemente por problema na manipulação de ponteiros, mas há ouras situações que podem ocorrer.

Pior quando não ocorre o [*segmentation fault*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). O hardware não pode impedir todo acesso equivocado na memória porque ele é válido e isso se torna um erro lógico, muito mais difícil de detectar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Normalmente em sistemas Unix eu tenho segmentos e páginas, certo? No caso, diz-se que uma página pertence a um único segmento (que por sua vez contém diversas páginas), ou é o contrario? Ou não tem nada a ver um com o outro?

Comment: O meu entendimento é que isto está correto, embora página virtual e página física são coisa diferentes, você pode ter uma mesma página física sendo apontada por páginas virtuais diferentes, em processos diferentes e portanto segmentos diferentes, apesar que só porque são processo diferentes. Segmentos são conceitos um pouco mais abstratos e são coisas muio maiores, tanto que existem poucos, páginas podem existir, no extremo, bilhões.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos em partes:
 O problema desse código é que a variável V é inicializada como **NULL**(apontando para lugar nenhum), logo na sequência é atribuído o valor 3 a ela, o que não faz sentido, pois o ponteiro ainda não está apontando para lugar algum.

**Segmentação de memória** é uma técnica muito usada nos sistemas operacionais para proteger o acesso indevido as posições de memória, um método alternativo a paginação de memória. Para tal parte da memória é removida do processo com o uso de registradores e se um dado quer ser acesso e está nesta parte removida ocorre um **Segmentation Fault**. A Segmentação de memória garante uma melhor proteção ao seu *software* contra edições de valores na memória via [Hexing](http://www.flexhex.com/docs/howtos/hex-editing.phtml), por exemplo.

[Fonte](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aqsj)