# As variáveis são alocadas aleatoriamente na memória?

Tags: c, ponteiro, gerenciamento-de-memória, stack, heap

Em um livro sobre C, no qual comecei a estudar sobre variáveis, dizia que as variáveis eram colocadas na memória aleatoriamente, por exemplo:

```
int a;
int b;

printf("a = %d\n", &a); --> 5000 (endereço) (%d ao invés de %p para simplificar)
printf("b = %d\n", &b); --> 7634 (endereço) (%d ao invés de %p para simplificar)
```

Porém, pelo que eu pesquisei, as variáveis locais (ou seja, dentro de uma função), elas ficam na *stack*, ou seja, sequencialmente. E as variáveis globais ficam aleatoriamente, ou seja, na *heap*. Se eu colocar um `printf()` nas variáveis locais, elas estão em endereços sequenciais, como nesse caso (compilado pelo GCC no Linux):

```
char a;
int n;
float b;

printf("a = %p\n", &a); --> a = 0x7ffeb85afd5f
printf("n = %p\n", &n); --> n = 0x7ffeb85afd60
printf("b = %p\n", &b); --> b = 0x7ffeb85afd64
```

Então, isso contradiz com o que eu aprendi no livro. Como entender isso?

Comment: [O que são e onde estão o “stack” e “heap”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/66203)

Comment: Lembre-se que nem todas as arquiteturas/plataformas possuem o mesmo tipo de gerenciamento de memória. Um bom exemplo seria o gerenciamento de memória virtual, que nem todos os sistemas/plataformas possuem um! Quando o autor diz que *as variáveis são colocadas aleatóriamente na memória*, significa que **quem controla esses endereços é o sistema/plataforma no qual o código está sendo executado. Esses endereços de memória são retornados pelo sistema e não podem ser determinados de forma "portável".** A propósito, qual é a data de publicação do livro que você mencionou ?

Comment: Livro de 2007, chamado Linguagem C, do Luis Damas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aleatoriamente nunca é o termo, sempre tem um certo determinismo, só não tem como antecipar onde exatamente quando escreve código, só em tempo de execução.

E vou falar aqui de [memória virtual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214744/101), a memória física certamente é organizada de outra forma e as coisas nem serão sequenciais fisicamente, mas não é aleatório, e isto não afeta o seu código. Vamos só no que interessa.

Antes tenha certeza que entende sobre [*stack* e *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

A linguagem C não determina que seja assim, vou falar como funciona de fato.

Não use variáveis globais. Elas ficam em uma área estática, que não é o *heap*, é reservada pelo compilador antecipadamente.

*Stack* é uma pilha, então é algo sequencial por definição. Você não tem controle onde exatamente estará ela (pode consultar isso em tempo de execução, como fez no código da pergunta), mas está longe de ser aleatória.

No *heap* também não é aleatório, tem critérios, mas é um pouco mais bagunçado. Ele é um monte, então a organização deixa a desejar, o objetivo é outro. Mas também não fica espalhado por toda a memória sem um sentido. E algumas variáveis estarão em sequência sim, especialmente em *arrays*. A organização apenas pode não ser tão óbvia.

O livro pode ter feito uma simplificação. Ou você pode ter interpretado errado o que estava escrito. Ou o livro é ruim mesmo.

Eu fiz simplificações, é muito mais complicado que isso, mas assim já é compreensível.

Comment: Eu acho que foi pra simplificar, pois o livro é ótimo. No segundo capítulo já entra o conceito de variáveis, então, não tinha como entrar nesse conceito de memoria stack e heap.

Comment: Mais uma dúvida: as funções também sao colocadas na memoria stack?

Comment: Não, fica na área estática.

Comment: Entendi, mas de acordo com esse site: https://blog.pantuza.com/artigos/heap-vs-stack , as funções ficam na pilha

Comment: Em nenhum lugar deste texto está escrito que as funções ficam na pilha.

Comment: Ah Sim, consegui esclarecer minha dúvida, muito obrigado.