# Diferença entre variável local VS variável global

Tags: c, variáveis, arduino, escopo-de-variáveis, microcontrolador

Nas minhas aulas de micro controladores as variáveis são sempre definidas globalmente e muito raramente localmente e gostava de saber o porquê, pois na minha cabeça faz diferença entre ser global ou local.

**1.** Qual a diferença a nível de velocidade entre uma e outra?

**2.** Tanto a variável local, como a variável global ocupa o mesmo espaço
    de memória?

**3.** A onde fica guardado a variável global na memória? E a variável
    local?

**4.** Existe mais alguma diferença significativa entre essas duas?

Realçar que não estou a programar em Arduino puro, estou a programar em C e depois coloco no microcontrolador do Arduino.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Qual a diferença a nível de velocidade entre uma e outra?

Nenhuma significativa. Elas são pré-alocadas. As locais precisam mexer em um ponteiro em registrador, mas o custo é próximo de zero.

> 2. Tanto a variável local, como a variável global ocupa o mesmo espaço de memoria?

Sim. Em condições normais.

> 3. A onde fica guardado a variável global na memoria? E a variável local?

Há uma [área específica da aplicação que reserva todo o espaço para variáveis globais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214744/101). As locais ficam na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

> 4. Existe mais alguma diferença significativa entre essas duas?

O [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101). E claro o escopo também, mas no contexto é menos importante. Para legibilidade de código variáveis globais são consideradas ruins justamente pelo escopo. No Arduino não há maiores problemas com as globais porque o acesso nunca é compartilhado por *threads* (mas se um dia tiver alguma forma de concorrência, passa ser um problema).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

Vou dizer o que eu sei sobre esse assunto.

**Respostas:**

1. até aonde eu sei não tem diferença.
2. sim.
3. memória ram.
4. sim! Uma variável local só pode ser usada dentro do método que ela foi criada, ou seja, se você tentar usar essa variável local em outro método, não vai conseguir.

Uma variável Global pode ser vista em qualquer lugar do sistema.