# Como um executável é apagado da memória?

Tags: memória, sistema-operacional, .exe

Esta pergunta não respondeu o que eu queria saber: [como um programa é carregado na memoria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209542/101)

O `.exe` é carregado inteiro na memória ou partes do programa são chamados apenas quando precisamos?

Depois que esta parte do programa é usada (por exemplo uma função de somar) ela é totalmente descartada da memória depois que é usada? Ou apenas o resultado fica lá? Ou talvez esta função fique totalmente lá até que fechamos o programa? Ou talvez ela seja descartada até que seja chamada?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

Ele não é apagado. Simples assim. E isso pode ser um problema de segurança se ele mantinha dados sensíveis na memória. Não que isso seja menos problema enquanto está rodando, mas se acontece algo que você desconhece e tem dados sensíveis o potencial de estrago é maior.

## Executável

Quando fala de um executável está falando da parte estática e fixa que está dentro de um arquivo binário contido em armazenamento de massa, e se leu a pergunta *linkada* (e os *links* contidos lá) com atenção verá que ele vai para a memória circunstancialmente através da memória virtual. E que no fim da sua execução não precisa fazer nada com isso, simplesmente o sistema operacional marca que as paginas de memória que tem o espelhamento do que está em disco (ou SSD ou NVRAM, ainda que este até poderia dispensar o espelhamento, mas é outro assunto) não estão mais em uso, e só. É praticamente mudar alguns bits no controle no sistema operacional ao término dele. E não muda qualquer outra coisa porque o que estaria na memória já está no "disco" igual.

Claro que essas páginas ficam livres para serem usadas por outros processamentos quaisquer, então em algum momento algo será escrito por cima e aquilo deixará de existir, mas não tem porque ter qualquer trabalho em ficar apagando alguma coisa. Isso precisa ficar bem claro.

## Memória

A sua aplicação ainda vai consumir memória para executar tudo o que precisa. Em geral ela fará isso em dois conceitos conhecidos como [*stack* e *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), mas para nosso objetivo aqui nem precisamos entender essa parte. Só precisamos saber que toda memória necessária para a aplicação, de uma forma ou de outra, será entregue pelo sistema operacional conforme solicitação. O sistema operacional tem uma contabilidade de tudo (nesse caso páginas de memória) que ele entregou para uma aplicação (ele tem um "banco de dados" simples na memória com isso).

O funcionamento dessa entrega é igual ao executável, na questão da memória virtual tem um espelhamento para a memória de massa, mas ao contrário do executável que parte do "disco" para espelhar em RAM, essa memória transitória parte da RAM e só vai para a memória de massa ("disco") se realmente for absolutamente necessário, que é o chamado *swap* de memória que nunca deveria acontecer em aplicações comportadas e que desejam ter boa performance (toda vez que faz *swap* o tempo de execução fica trágico, para dizer algo condescendente).

Então quando a aplicação termina, essas páginas de memória são marcadas pelo sistema operacional, faz parte da tarefa dele, como sendo páginas livres para reuso em qualquer necessidade do SO. Simples e rápido assim (em muitos casos ficará abaixo de um microssegundo, pelo menos essa parte, pode demorar mais para a aplicação em si fazer o encerramento).

E justamente porque nada é apagado pode ser inseguro e outra aplicação enxergar aquilo "sem querer". Algumas linguagens limpam o que for usar, outras deixam você fazer isso, e quando digo limpar, muitas vezes nem é algo que é feito de verdade, a limpeza pode ser só escrever algo em cima do que já tinha para uso direto na hora de usar, mas ainda está tudo lá.

## Conclusão

Devem existir ferramentas para fazer alguma limpeza se for necessário, mas em geral se precisa que apague então faça antes de terminar a aplicação, ou melhor ainda, não coloque na memória algo sensível, até porque nada garante que será apagado mesmo, várias situações podem ocorrer e impedir isso.

O que mais precisa entender sobre tudo isso é a memória virtual. Acho que não tem algo específico e direto mas o *link* da pergunta em [O que é segmentação de memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214744/101) já é um começo para começar pesquisar mais.

Quanto à questão de carga do executável, a resposta *linkada* responde perfeitamente o que quer saber, basta ler com atenção. Só estou respondendo a parte da finalização que de fato lá não fala em detalhes e a pessoa teria que inferir que é assim (alguns conseguem, outros não, por isso estou respondendo).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu ia lincar em um comentário para o AP junto do Stack e Heap essa aqui [O que é Garbage Collector](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/255788/137387), mas como você já deu uma resposta.O comentário perdeu o sentido. Veja serve de complemento.

Comment: Nem acho que faça sentido, o GC não tem a ver com isso, na verdade nem o *stack* e *heap*, o SO não tem noção disso. Seria legal se o SO tivesse mecanismo pra pelo menos ajudar o GC, ficaria bem melhor, incrível que mesmo depois de quase todas linguagens usarem algo assim ainda não tenha. A pergunta aqui é sobre algo diferente do gerenciamento de memória da aplicação.