# Alocação dinâmica de memória, sem uso, não consome memória?

Tags: c, c++, memória, alocação

Estava fazendo uns testes no meu programa que aloca dinamicamente uma quantidade de 4*N bytes na memória, para ver como estava o consumo de RAM no gerenciador de tarefas. Eu estava sempre fazendo os testes inserindo valores, preenchendo o espaço que aloquei.

Para fazer os testes executarem mais rápido, decidi retirar a inserção dos valores, pensando que o consumo de RAM seria o mesmo, já que o espaço alocado seria o mesmo. Para minha surpresa, ao abrir o gerenciador de tarefas, o consumo de RAM era praticamente igual ao consumo na inicialização do programa.

Então decidi fazer um simples código para confirmar isso:

```
int main() {
    int * ptr = new int[1000000]; // O consumo deve ser superior à 3900KB

    int i;
    cin >> i;
}
```

Ao executar, podemos ver no gerenciador de tarefas que o programa consome nada de memória. Como isso é possível se eu aloquei espaço!? Então aqui estão minhas dúvidas quanto à isso:

- Por que não há consumo de memória se não inserir valores?
- O que ocorre com o espaço alocado, enquanto a *stack* ainda está viva?
- Quem é responsável por isso, *runtime* ou OS?

Comment: Forçando a utilização do espaço alocado normalmente já da para ver alguma coisa a mexer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/17NLF.gif

Comment: @Isac Sim, foi isso que disse na minha pergunta. Quando insere valor no espaço alocado, o GM mostra um maior consumo. Mas enquanto isso não ocorre, o consumo é o mesmo de se não houvesse alocado qualquer espaço.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Gerenciador de tarefas

Gerenciador de tarefas não é uma ferramenta para olhar consumo real de memória.

O primeiro erro que as pessoas vão achar olhando para ele é que o sistema operacional consome muita memória. E sim, ele consome, ele põe tudo o que pode na memória porque isso é otimização, o que está na memória é acessado mais rápido. Isso é *feature*, das boas, não *bug* como as pessoas acham.

E é uma das maiores *fake news* espalhadas pela internet e por isso tanta gente na área não tem a menor ideia do que está falando, igual acontece em toda sociedade. Sem saber todos os detalhes sobre algo a pessoa não consegue avaliar de fato o que ocorre e ela está fadada a produzir *fake news* sofrendo do [Efeito Dunning Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect). Precisa mudar.

O mesmo acontece com a aplicação. A memória da aplicação não é alocada byte por byte necessário. A alocação é feita sempre pelo sistema operacional, então a aplicação precisa chamá-lo e dizer que quer memória, e o OS entrega o pedido, se for possível.

A forma exata como ele fará isso é problema dele, inclusive é feito em esquema de memória virtual, não terá acesso de forma linear.

O OS mostra na ferramenta de inspeção de uso de memória da aplicação (Gerenciador de Tarefas) conforme ele entregou e não foi devolvido. Note que ele é detalhado e sabe o que está em uso real e o que não está, ainda que já esteja reservado.

As linguagens não devolvem algo que será usado de novo logo depois. Mesmo o uso real é complicado porque as linguagens reaproveitam o que já foi usado e para o sistema operacional o que já foi usado tem uso real, mesmo que no momento não esteja em uso de fato. Ele só sabe se está só reservado ou se já foi usado de fato (*committed*).

Sem falar que o OS trabalha com páginas de memória e não bytes de fato, até porque isso é irrelevante para grandes consumos.

E as linguagens, em seu *runtime*, não ficam pedindo byte por byte que precisam, acessar o OS é bem caro, lento, então ele pede memória em blocos, quanto mais pedir mais eficiente fica em processamento, e menos em consumo.

Por tudo isso o gerenciador de memória não serve para avaliar a individualidade de uma aplicação, só para o coletivo é útil.

Precisaria de uma ferramenta que conhece e tem acesso ao que o *runtime* faz para ter uma informação confiável.

Nada disso explica o que aconteceu neste caso, só quis desmistificar esse uso.

## Otimização

Onde a variável `ptr` foi usada na aplicação?

Se algo não é usado, por que o compilador manteria a instrução no código que cria um absurdo de memória<sup>*</sup> se essa informação nunca será usada? Ele não mantém. Ele otimiza o código matando essa instrução inútil.

## Outros fatores

Na verdade pode ocorrer várias outras coisas que eu não sei, não lembro ou não estou percebendo. Até porque isso é detalhe de implementação e pode mudar a qualquer momento.

E é isso que eu tenho que saber, isso não é algo fixo. Se eu quiser saber de fato o que ocorreu terei que fazer vários experimentos, inspecionar em detalhes, tudo com fundamentação em algo correto, se eu errar em algo terei uma informação falsa.

Se alguém falar que ocorreu outra coisa neste caso específico não vou me surpreender. Se falarem que no compilador tal, uma outra versão, forma de compilação, ou em OS diferente, até por causa da diferença de tratamento do *runtime*, acontecer diferente do observado no seu teste, será algo potencialmente esperado.

## *Stack*

Se fosse na pilha aí também não mostraria mudança porque a alocação de memória já ocorreu no começo da execução para toda a pilha e não ao consumo real.

## Para começar a se aprofundar

- [O que é segmentação de memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/214744/101)
- [O que é segmentation fault?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177185/101)
- [Como um programa é carregado na memória e depois executado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209542/101)
- [Como um executável é apagado da memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/450743/101)
- [As variáveis são alocadas aleatoriamente na memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252011/101)
- [Como o malloc() organiza a memória?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/254358/101)
- [Como o "free()" sabe quanto de memória tem que liberar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178174/101)
- [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)
- [What does the brk() system call do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6988487/221800)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

---

<sup>* Ainda que ele nem saiba exatamente disto, mas se não usa, não é útil, mesmo algo mínimo</sup>