# Leitura de vetor em C está errada

Tags: c, struct, stack

```
struct cadastro{
int codigo;
char nome[200];
char cpf[11];
char rg[10];
char tel[12];
char end[100];

}cadastro;//struct do tipo cadastro.

struct cadastro cd[max];//vetor da funcao cadastro de cliente
```

Montei um menu, com `do - while`, e com a obtenção do parâmetro e usando `switch` redireciono aos módulos de acordo.

O que deveria acontecer, eu chamo a função `vender()`

```
void vender()
{
int cod,client;
char resp;

system("cls");

printf("------------------------------------------\n");
printf("------------Seja bem vindo----------------\n");
printf("------------------------------------------\n");
printf("Por favor entre com o codigo de cliente:  \n");
scanf("%d",&cod);

system("cls");

for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    if(cd[i].codigo == cod)
    {
        client = i;
    }
    else
    {
        if(cd[i].codigo != cod)
        {
            printf("Usuario nao cadastrado, deseja cadastrar?[s/n]: ");
            scanf("%s",&resp);

            if(resp == 's')
            {
                cad_cliente();
            }
            else
            {
                menu();
            }
        }
    }
}

system("cls");

printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
printf("Cod: %d\n",cd[client].codigo);
printf("Nome: %s\n",cd[client].nome);
printf("Tel: %s\n",cd[client].tel);
printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
}
```

E verifico se existe um usuário cadastrado, não tendo, vou e cadastro, volto e chamo a função `vender()`, consulto pelo código do cliente que eu cadastrei e nada acontece...

Fiz alguma coisa errada nesse trecho de código?

[Código completo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52949/101).

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 5):

Em alguns pontos já faz melhor do que alguns iniciantes. Mas ainda tem alguns erros básicos. Tem uma quantidade grande de erros pequenos e grandes no que está fazendo. Vou apenas resolver o mais sério no trecho apresentado:

```
void vender() {
    system("cls");
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("------------Seja bem vindo----------------\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Por favor entre com o codigo de cliente:  \n");
    int cod;
    scanf("%d", &cod);
    system("cls");
    int client = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (cd[i].codigo == cod) {
            client = i;
            break; //se achou não precisa continuar procurando
        }
    }
    if (client == -1) { //se ainda é -1 não acho a posição do cliente, então não existe
        printf("Usuario nao cadastrado, deseja cadastrar?[s/n]: ");
        char resp;
        scanf("%s", &resp);
        if (resp == 's') {
            cad_cliente();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    system("cls");
    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Cod: %d\n", cd[client].codigo);
    printf("Nome: %s\n", cd[client].nome);
    printf("Tel: %s\n", cd[client].tel);
    printf("-------------------------------------------\n");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/DataInput.c).

Vou falar uma coisa que não costuma adiantar para a maioria das pessoas. Procure sempre organizar bem o código (o seu está acima de média), dê nomes significativos para as variáveis e mantenho um padrão limpo. A única recomendação a mais que eu faria é separar os parênteses do `if`, `for`, `while`, já que eles não são funções e pode ficar estranho.

## `else if`

Talvez você não conhecia o `else if` o que simplificaria um pouco seu código. Ele executa aquele bloco se atender aquela condição. Mas no caso específico o `else if` nem seria necessário já que a condição deste segundo `if` seria o oposto do primeiro. Então basta um `else`. O `else` é justamente para executar um bloco com condição oposta ao `if`. Acho que ainda não entendeu a função do `if`.

Mas no caso específico havia um outro problema de lógica. Ele não fazia o que imaginava. O que ele fazia é que se o código escolhido não fosse o primeiro do cadastro, ele considerava que o cliente não estava cadastrado. Mas poderia estar nos próximos códigos. Tem que analisar tudo e só se não encontrar em nenhum é que deve decidir que o usuário não está cadastrado. Fiz uma mudança. Nem vou explicar em detalhes, acho que não está no ponto para isto.

## Recursão acidental

Havia uma chamada do `menu()`. Isto não só não só não é necessário já que se deixar prosseguir, o código voltará para ele. Mas chamar um código do qual aquela função foi chamada criará um ciclo indesejado e que cria um potencial de de [estouro de pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95824/101) (não vou entrar em detalhes aqui, é um assunto mais avançado, por enquanto se atenha a não criar ciclos de chamada). Se é para encerrar e voltar para a função chamadora, basta usar um `return`, não a chame novamente.

Me preocupa a chamada do `cad_cliente()` ali também. Até poderia não ser problema, mas ela está errada e vai causar problemas. Note que em todas as funções está usando essa chamada ao `menu`. Precisa entender o retorno das funções. Você deve chamar algo, esse algo executar e encerrar, é um vai e volta:

```
função chamadora <-> função chamada
```

Seu código faz:

```
função chamadora -> função chamada -> função chamadora
```

Quando terminar a função chamadora em segundo lugar, ela voltará para a função chamada, que depois voltará para a função chamadora. Garanto que não é isto que deseja.

No primeiro exemplo quando a função chamada encerrar, ela não chama nada, ela volta para quem chamou, é assim que deve ser. [As chamadas de funções devem funcionar como pilhas e não como ciclos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Não vou olhar todo o código mas olhando a função de cadastro de cliente vi outro problema de ciclo. Ali tem uma recursão (é algo que vai aprender no futuro). Recursão pode ser útil, mas em casos específicos e quando se saber o que está fazendo, não pode ser usado em qualquer caso e não pode ser por acidente. Se deseja fazer outro cadastro deve controlar isto com uma laço, como fez corretamente no `menu()` (ainda que o `case 8` é necessário ter um `exit(1)`, pode sair por vias normais terminando o laço. Pode até funcionar do seu jeito, mas estará aprendendo errado pelo objetivo inicial.

Percebo que ainda não entendeu bem o funcionamento de laços e principalmente de como funciona uma função, principalmente como ela é encerrada. Não passe pra frente sem ter completo domínio disto.

## Organização

Também deixei a declaração de `resp` mais próxima de onde ele é usada. Fiz mesmo com as demais variáveis, mas mantendo o mesmo escopo. A técnica de declarar tudo o que vai usar antes é antiquada. E o próprio código já é mais moderno no uso de `i`.

Deveria evitar variáveis globais como ocorreu, mas talvez seja cedo para ensinar o jeito correto de fazer isto. Tem várias coisas que deveriam ser feitas de forma diferente, mas não dá para explicar aqui e não sei se deveria fazer já, você vai perceber com o tempo conforme for evoluindo os problemas de algumas coisas feitas neste código.

Nem vou falar do `fflsush(stdin)` e do `gets()`. Isto é um erro, mas se estiver funcionando, vai assim por enquanto, mais tarde aprender fazer o certo.

Depois que melhorar e ainda tiver dúvidas pode postar em outra pergunta para ajudarmos mais.

## Conclusão

A minha conclusão é que está tentando fazer um código complexo demais para sua capacidade atual de entendimento de algoritmos. Deveria voltar um passo pra trás e entender cada construção individual na sua plenitude antes de tentar fazer códigos mais complexos unindo os vários recursos. Se pular etapas vai ter muita dificuldade e provavelmente aprenderá errado o que lhe complicará para sempre.

Comment: Boa noite, bigown primeiramente, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, e concordo quanto aos erros de programação, mesmo por que como eu disse aprendi do 0 ao que "sei" em 1 semana passando por diversas dificuldades e com pouca instrução de estudos,oque acontece eh que estou em uma turma a frente do meu conhecimento, e esse "trabalho" esta a frente do meu conhecimento.