# Bit array in c duvida

Tags: c

Galera estava olhando uns exemplos de bit array e vi a seguinte função:

```
char get_bit(char *array, int index)
{

    return 1 & (array[index / 8] >> (index % 8));
}
```

Não consegui entender porque o autor usou  `>>` em vez de `<<` para retornar um bit.

Comment: O que você não entendeu? Você sabe pra que serve o `<<` e não o `>>`?

Comment: não  , só não entendi o porque do >> nesse contexto , porque por exemplo na operação de setar um bit e usado o <<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em um Array de *bytes*, cada um deles ocupa uma posição de memória.

Cada *byte* tem 8 *bits*. Ou seja, em cada posição do *array* nós temos oito bits, então temos que ter um jeito de pegar cada um individualmente.

Para facilitar, vamos visualizar cada *bit* em seu endereço:

```
byte                  10100111 10010001 01101111 01111111 ....
                                            ^- usaremos o bit 19 como exemplo

endereço de memória   n        n+1      n+2      n+3      ...

posição do bit:       7......0 15.....8 23....16 31....24 ...
(bit menos significante para a direita)
```

Perceba que a cada 8 posições de bit, avançamos 1 posição de memória. Portanto, para saber a posição do bit na memória, precisamos dividir a posição do bit por 8. Aí entra esta parte do código:

```
return 1 & (array[index / 8] >> (index % 8));
                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

Ok, no nosso exemplo, o bit 19 está em 19 / 8, o que dá 2 (em inteiros). Já sabemos então que temos que ler o endereço `n+2`, que tem este valor:

```
0b01101111
```

Bom, nosso `index` é 19. Já usamos o 19 para obter o `n+2`, dividindo por 8, mas temos que saber onde fica o bit certo. Para isso pegamos `19 % 8`, que é esta parte do código:

```
return 1 & (array[index / 8] >> (index % 8));
                                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

Se o código fosse meu, provavelmente eu usaria `index & 7`, por questão de gosto, mas no fim dá na mesma. No caso, o valor retornado é 3

Portanto, nosso "cálculo" ficou assim:

```
return 1 & ( 0b01101111 >> 3 )
                   ^
```

O operador `>>` desloca o byte 3x pra direita, afinal, quem implementou a função **optou** por contar da direita para a esquerda:

```
return 1 & ( 0b00001101 )
                      ^
```

Finalmente o `1 &` vai descartar o resto do byte e retornar só o nosso bit 19, que no caso é `1`.

Quando você faz o inverso, que é setar ou resetar o *bit*, vai justamente usar o operador contrário, o `<<`, para setar o *bit* na sua posição certa, algo mais ou menos assim (dá pra otimizar, e pode ter algum erro bobo, foi só exemplo):

```
array[index / 8] = array[index / 8] & ~(1 << (index % 8)) | (bit & 1) << (index % 8);
```

**E se a pessoa tivesse optado pelo mais significante à direita?**

```
11100101 10001001 11110110 11111110 ...
0......7 8.....15 16....31
                     ^
```

Simples, a fórmula seria algo assim:

```
return 127 & ( array[index / 8] << (index % 8) ) / 127;
```

E aconteceria isto:

```
return 127 & ( 0b11110110 << 3 ) / 127;
                    ^
```

Reduzindo a isto:

```
return 127 & ( 0b10110000 ) / 127
                 ^
```

O que daria `1` da mesma forma.

Caso queira mais detalhes do operador `>>`, aqui tem uma breve explicação:

> [Para que servem os operadores | & << >>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52949/70)

<sub><sup>(Não é a mesma linguagem, mas é o mesmo funcionamento.)</sup></sub>

Comment: Usei 0bXXXXXXXX para representar binário, mas vale notar que isso não é padrão nos compiladores mais velhos. Oficialmente foi introduzido pelo C++14, mas já era uma extensão de alguns compiladores, em especial os de sistemas embedded.

Answer (score -1):

`<<` é usado para definir um valor, e `>>` para obter o valor.

Comment: Posso te pedir uma referência que diz isso? Tenho a impressão que você está enganado.