# Otimização de processamento e memória em laço

Tags: c#, lista, loop, memória, otimização

O código é simples e está funcionando perfeitamente, mas queria dicas de como otimizá-lo, quais seriam os melhores métodos a se utilizar para alocar menos memória, boas práticas, etc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> numeros = new List<int>();
        List<int> pares = new List<int>();
        List<int> impares = new List<int>();

        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            int n = random.Next(1, 99);
            numeros.Add(n);
        }

        foreach (int item in numeros)
        {
            if (item % 2 == 0)
                pares.Add(item);
            else
                impares.Add(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Todos os números:");

        int index = 0;

        foreach (int item in numeros)
        {
            if (index == numeros.Count - 1)
                Console.Write(item + "." + "\n");
            else
                Console.Write(item + ", ");

            index++;
        }

        index = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Números pares:");

        foreach (int item in pares)
        {
            if (index == pares.Count - 1)
                Console.Write(item + "." + "\n");
            else
                Console.Write(item + ", ");

            index++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Números ímpares:");

        index = 0;

        foreach (int item in impares)
        {
            if (index == impares.Count - 1)
                Console.Write(item + "." + "\n");
            else
                Console.Write(item + ", ");

            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: qual seria o requisito ? parece um daqueles exercícios de faculdade, e tem professor que pede pra cada processo ser feito em um loop diferente, rs, teria q ver os requisitos pra saber o que pode ser alterado

Comment: É bem isso mesmo. Não tem regra, basta manter o resultado da maneira que está. Quero aprender um pouco sobre otimização para aplicar nos códigos mais complexos futuramente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas algumas alterações, ainda é possível fazer mais, mas não vejo necessidade de complicar. rs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> numeros = new List<int>();
        List<int> pares = new List<int>();
        List<int> impares = new List<int>();

        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            int n = random.Next(1, 99);
            numeros.Add(n);
            if (n % 2 == 0)
                pares.Add(n);
            else
                impares.Add(n);

        }

        Console.WriteLine("Todos os números:");


        for (int i =0; i < numeros.Count; i++)
           Console.Write( numeros[i].ToString() + (i == numeros.Count-1 ? ".\r\n" : ", " ));


        Console.WriteLine("\nNúmeros pares:");

        for (int i =0; i < pares.Count; i++)
           Console.Write( pares[i].ToString() + (i == pares.Count-1 ? ".\r\n" : ", " ));


        Console.WriteLine("\nNúmeros ímpares:");

        for (int i =0; i < impares.Count; i++)
           Console.Write( impares[i].ToString() + (i == impares.Count-1 ? ".\r\n" : ", " ));

    }
}
```

Coloquei no [**.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yM0cYi)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Poderia explicar essa linha? `(i == numeros.Count-1 ? ".\r\n" : ", " )`

Comment: Deixa pra lá, já descobri do que se trata :)

Comment: rsrs, operador ternário, =]

Answer (score 3):

Otimização pode ser muita coisa. Pode ser por performance, consumo de memória, pode ser por código ou até outras coisas a serem definidas. Otimização tem que testar. E o que vale hoje pode não valer amanhã.

Otimizar este código não deve trazer muita vantagem. Umas das poucas melhorias de performance é achar se é par com operador de bit que costuma mais rápido que o operador de resto, mas o compilador poderia fazer uma otimização e não mudar nada. Algumas coisa talvez ainda possam ser feitas, mas depende de testes para comprovar que são otimizações.

O resto eu consigo apenas diminuir e modernizar o código. Claro que poderia eliminar uma ou duas das listas, o que poderia ocupar metade da memória, mas não vejo vantagens. Tem redução que provavelmente cria otimização, por exemplo retirar um *branching* (comparação `if` ou ternário) dentro de um laço como eu fiz nas impressões.

Como não tem requisitos fica difícil saber o que fazer. Na verdade talvez poderia cortar mais alguma coisa.

Como a impressão das listas são idênticas poderia jogar em uma função para eliminar duplicidade de código, mas pode ser que não seja a intenção.

Tem outros pequenos detalhes que poderiam ser diferentes, mas depende de gosto.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var numeros = new List<int>();
        var pares = new List<int>();
        var impares = new List<int>();
        var random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) numeros.Add(random.Next(1, 99));
        foreach (int item in numeros) {
            if ((item & 1) == 0) {
                pares.Add(item);
            } else {
                impares.Add(item);
            }
        }
        WriteLine("Todos os números:");
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Count - 1; i++) Write(numeros[i] + ", ");
        WriteLine(numeros[numeros.Count - 1] + ".");
        WriteLine("\nNúmeros pares:");
        for (int i = 0; i < pares.Count - 1; i++) Write(pares[i] + ", ");
        WriteLine(pares[pares.Count - 1] + ".");
        WriteLine("\nNúmeros ímpares:");
        for (int i = 0; i < impares.Count - 1; i++) Write(impares[i] + ", ");
        WriteLine(impares[impares.Count - 1] + ".");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/jjnkAF). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KtTU4I). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Optimization.cs).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Claro que pra esse código não precisa de nenhuma preocupação com memória e desempenho, mas preciso aprender desde já para futuros códigos mais complexos. Além de, também, aprender as reduções e abreviações. Não entendi bem a linha que determina os pares `if ((item & 1) == 0)`, poderia explicar?

Comment: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190579/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52949/101. Ele testa apenas um bit em uma operação de custo muito baixo. Só o bit menos significativo já identifica se é par ou ímpar, não tem porque fazer uma cálculo complexo como é a divisão para pegar o resto.