# chr() valor fora do range (0..255)

Tags: php

Estou estudando esta função, porém estou tendo dificuldades para entender quando passamos um valor fora do range (0..255) para esta função.

Na documentação oficial ele apresenta um algoritmo para encontrar o valor correto, mas não consegui pegar a ideia e conseguir reproduzir.

Tenho o seguinte exemplo:

```
echo chr(300);
```

O que me resulta em: `,` que possui a posição 44.

Mas como é feito o calculo de que ao passar o valor 300 ele me retorna o correspondente de posição 44?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicar como ocorre exatamente internamente no interpretador de scripts PHP (no windows o `php.exe`), PHP é escrito em em [c](/questions/tagged/c), o código é este:

- https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/string.c#L2776

Código:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(chr)
{
    zend_long c;

    if (ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 1) {
        WRONG_PARAM_COUNT;
    }

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START_EX(ZEND_PARSE_PARAMS_QUIET, 1, 1)
        Z_PARAM_LONG(c)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END_EX(c = 0);

    c &= 0xff;
    ZVAL_INTERNED_STR(return_value, ZSTR_CHAR(c));
}
```

A linha responsável é esta:

```
c &= 0xff;
```

Esta notação `0x` que esta a frente do `ff` significa hexadecimal (base 16), o calculo dele é feito assim:

- cada `f` vale 15, então 16 elevado a 1 é 16 mesmo
- ficando `15 * 16`
- 16 elevado a 0 é 1
- ficando `15 * 1`
- soma ambos

O cálculo:

```
15 * 16^1 + 15 * 16^0 = 255
(15 * 16) + (15 * 1)  = 255
```

O valor final é `255`

> **Nota importante:** com exceção do próprio zero, qualquer valor elevado a zero resultará em 1, por exemplo:
>
> - 3<sup>0</sup> = 1
> - 10<sup>0</sup> = 1
> - 22<sup>0</sup> = 1
> - 2018<sup>0</sup> = 1
>
> Já o zero não pode ser determinado:
>
> - 0<sup>0</sup> = indeterminado
>
> Então por **convenção** em programação é considerada como sendo igual a **1** (0<sup>0</sup> = 1), um exemplo em PHP pode-se testar assim com a função `pow(base, expoente)`:
>
> ```
> var_dump(pow(16, 0));
> var_dump(pow(0, 0));
> ```
>
> Ou no PHP 5.6+:
>
> ```
> var_dump(16 ** 0);
> var_dump(0 ** 0);
> ```
>
> Exemplo https://ideone.com/QAx9Dh

---

Apenas para explicar melhor a fórmula do base 16, se fosse isto `0xff00` seria assim:

```
15 * 16^3 + 15 * 16^2 = 65280
```

Operação:

```
(15 * 256) + (15 * 4096) = 65280
3840       + 61440       = 65280
```

O valor `65280`

- então o valor mais a direita é sempre elevado a zero
- o segundo mais a direita elevado a um
- o terceiro da direita para esquerda é elevado a dois

E assim por diante, como no segundo exemplo tínhamos dois zeros depois do `ff` (o que resulta em zero no calculo e por isto desconsiderei na formula), então um deles foi elevado a 2 e o outro elevado a três.

---

Voltando a fórmula, no resultado da execução do programa (da função `PHP_FUNCTION(chr)`) teremos isto:

```
c &= 255;
```

O operador `&=` equivale a isto `c = c & 255;`, este operador `&` (ou `&=`) é um operador *bitwise* chamado `AND` (**não confundir** com `&&`, apesar de semelhante) para lógica binária, então em uma operação ele vai comparar bit a bit e vai retornar um 1 sempre que ambos quando comparados forem 1, tem uma resposta no site sobre isto:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/52952/3635

Então 255 é igual a `011111111` e o valor que você colocou 300 seria igual a `0100101100`, como 255 em bits é menor então é adicionado um zero a sua esquerda (mesmo vale se fosse ao contrário `255 & 300`):

```
255:       0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
300:       0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
------------------------------------------------
Resultado: 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
```

Então teremos `0000101100` que convertido resulta em `44`

**Nota:** para facilitar entender as operações pode-se remover os zeros a esquerda, assim:

```
255:       0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
300:       1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
---------------------------------------------
Resultado: 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0
```

O valor convertido será o mesmo no final.

---

Essas operações podem ser feitas em diversas linguagens de programação (não sei se tem alguma que não suporte), então pode testar em JavaScript:

```js
var valor = prompt('Insira o numero');
var range = 255;

valor = parseInt(valor);

if (valor) {
    var x = valor & range;
    alert(x);
} else {
    alert('Numero inválido');
}
```

Um exemplo em PHP seria:

```
<?php

$valor = 44;
$range = 255;

$x = $valor & $range;

var_dump($x);
```

Comment: Cara, eu revirei o repositório do PHP atrás desse trecho... Muito bom!

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado, agora ficou super claro.