# O que significa & em Python? Qual o seu nome? é um operador?

Tags: python, loop, operadores

Estava eu olhando sobre o *loop while* no Python, e tudo ia bem, mas do nada vejo: "&", que mesmo buscando não consegui encontrar nada sobre.

```
i = 0
while i &lt; 5 :
     print(i)
     i = i + 1
```

Saída:

> ```
> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso não existe em Pyhton, isso é praticamente um erro de digitação, se você colocar isso para compilar dará erro. Isto é HTML puro (antes da exibição), é a forma do HTML representar o caracteres `<` sem confundir com abertura de *tag*. Então este código na verdade é isto:

```
i = 0
while i < 5:
     print(i)
     i = i + 1
```

Este funciona perfeitamente. [Veja o código original **não** funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/r2wzMO). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/LesserThan.py).

Então provavelmente está usando alguma tecnologia com defeito que trabalhe com código na web que acabou se confundindo e apesar de estar mostrando isso, só pode executando porque ele está com o código real correto e não isso.

Python tem um `&` e ele é o mesmo que em outras linguagens, é o [operador "e" *bitwise*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52949/101), mas nada tem a ver com esse código.